# Linear regression cost function and gradient descent

Tags: linear-regression

I have been studying data science and ML topics for a while and I always get sucked at one point that makes a great confusion for me.

In courses like Andrew Ng's, it is defined that the error between the predicted value and the true value from e.g. Linear regression is expressed by:

**error = predicted_value - y**

In some other tutorials/courses, the error is presented as:

**error = y - predicted_value**

Also, for instance, on Udacity's data science Nanodegree, the gradient descent weights update is given by:

**error = y - predicted_value**

**W_new = W + learn_rate * np.matmul(error, X)**

At the same time, in several other books/courses, the same procedure is given by :

**error = predicted_value - y**

**W_new = W - learn_rate * np.matmul(error, X)**

Could someone help me out with those different notations?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Following @bottaio answer, I got the following:

First case :

```
# compute errors
y_pred = np.matmul(X, W) + b
error = y_pred - y

# compute steps
W_new = W - learn_rate * np.matmul(error, X)
b_new = b - learn_rate * error.sum()
return W_new, b_new
```

Second case :

```
# compute errors
y_pred = np.matmul(X, W) + b
error = y - y_pred

# compute steps
W_new = W + learn_rate * np.matmul(error, X)
b_new = b + learn_rate * error.sum()
return W_new, b_new
```

Running the first and second cases, I get :
[image]

Third case :

```
# compute errors
y_pred = np.matmul(X, W) + b
error = y_pred - y

# compute steps
W_new = W + learn_rate * np.matmul(error, X)
b_new = b + learn_rate * error.sum()
return W_new, b_new
```

Running the third case, I get :

[image]

That's exactly the intuition I'm trying to achieve.
Whats the relation between using the **error = y - y_pred** and having to use the step computation as positive **W_new = W + learn_rate * np.matmul(error, X)** instead of **W_new = W - learn_rate * np.matmul(error, X)** ?

Thank you for all the support!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
error = predicted_value - y
error' = y - predicted_value = -error
W = W + lr * matmul(error, X) = W + lr * matmul(-error', X) = W - lr * matmul(-error', X)
```

These two expressions are two ways of looking at the same thing. You propagate error backwards.

To be honest, the second states more clearly what is going on under the hood - error is just a difference between what model predicted relative to ground truth (explains predicted - y). And gradient descent step is about changing weights in opposite direction to gradient (explains minus).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your reply! I just updated my question following your answer!